# ARM char device driver initialization isn't creating /dev/ file

Tags: linux, module, kernel, driver, device

I am writing a driver for the GPIO pins on an ARM platform. 
My driver works correctly and I've avoided the problem until
now by manually mknod'ing a device file.

my initialization code:

`static int __init gpio_init (void)
{`

```
    void *ptr_error;
    if (register_chrdev(249, "gpio_device", &fops) < 0){
            printk(KERN_INFO "Registering device failed\n");
            return -EINVAL;
    }

    if ((device_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "gpio_device"))
                                                    == NULL){
            unregister_chrdev_region(DEV_T, 1);
            printk(KERN_INFO "Class creation failed\n");
            return -EINVAL;
    }
    ptr_error = device_create(device_class, NULL, DEV_T, NULL, "gpio_device");
    if (IS_ERR(ptr_error)){
            class_destroy(device_class);
            unregister_chrdev_region(DEV_T, 1);
            printk(KERN_INFO "Device creation failed\n");
            return -EINVAL;
    }

    cdev_init(&c_dev, &fops);

    if (cdev_add(&c_dev, DEV_T, 1)){
            device_destroy(device_class, DEV_T);
            class_destroy(device_class);
            unregister_chrdev_region(DEV_T, 1);
            printk(KERN_INFO "Cdev add failed\n");
            return -EINVAL;
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "Guten tag, GPIO driver initialized\n");
    return SUCCESS;
```

}

This runs with no errors, except no file "gpio_device" is created in /dev.

I'm cross compiling for ARM onto kernel 2.6.39.4. (using arm-linux-gcc)

As I understand it, device_create *should* be creating the /dev file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out what was going on here. 
We are using BuildRoot to create our custom 
linux, and the it turns out we had compiled 
out the udev device file management system.

So that's why this doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, Can you help me with this ques of mine
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481886/device-driver-fn-is-not-being-called-when-system-call-in-userspace-is-called

Answer (score 3):

I tried running your code and found a few mistakes:

- When you register with `register_chrdev()`, you should unregister with `unregister_chrdev()`. `unregister_chrdev_region()` is used to unregister a registration done with `alloc_chrdev_region()` or `register_chrdev_region()`.
- A call to `register_chrdev()` registers minor numbers 0-255 for the given major, and sets up a default `cdev` structure for each, therefore, you do not need to deal with the `cdev_init()` & `cdev_add()`.
- You should check the error using `IS_ERR` & `PTR_ERR` for `class_create()` & `device_create()` as `PTR_ERR` will turn the return pointer to the error code with a cast.

You can read more here: [Char Device Registration](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-3-sect-4).

After applying the modification I mentioned, the `/dev/gpio_device` is created without `mknod`:

```
int init_module(void)
{   
    void *ptr_error;
    struct cdev* c_dev;
    int result=0;

    /* register_chrdev */
    result=register_chrdev(my_major, "gpio_device", &fops);
    if (result < 0)
    {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Registering device failed\n");
    return result;
    }

    DEV_T = MKDEV(my_major, my_minor);

    /* class_create */
    device_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "gpio_device");
    if (IS_ERR(device_class))
    {
    unregister_chrdev(my_major, "gpio_device");
    printk(KERN_INFO "Class creation failed\n");
    return PTR_ERR(device_class);
    }

    /* device_create */
    ptr_error = device_create(device_class, NULL, DEV_T, NULL, "gpio_device");
    if (IS_ERR(ptr_error))
    {
    class_destroy(device_class);
    unregister_chrdev(my_major, "gpio_device");
    printk(KERN_INFO "Device creation failed\n");
    return PTR_ERR(ptr_error);
    }

    /* //removed
    cdev_init(&c_dev, &fops);
    if (cdev_add(&c_dev, DEV_T, 1)){
    device_destroy(device_class, DEV_T);
    class_destroy(device_class);
    unregister_chrdev_region(DEV_T, 1);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Cdev add failed\n");
    return -EINVAL;
    }*/

    printk(KERN_INFO "Guten tag, GPIO driver initialized\n");
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I made your changes and while it compiles and inserts without error, it still doesn't create a /dev/ file. It IS registered in /proc/devices however, and the driver is live in /proc/modules.