# device driver fn is not being called when system call in userspace is called

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, device

i am re-writing a scull device driver.
I have written the open/read/write fns in driver code. 
`echo "hello" > /dev/myscull0` shows the data being written successfully to my device driver, and open() -> write() ->release() has been called in driver successfully.

Similarly, other operations using standard bash commands are successfull when operated on driver device file. Eg: cat /dev/myscull0 execute drivers read() call.

Now, i am writing a user space program to operate on my device file.

```
void
scull_open(){
    char device_name[DEV_NAME_LENGTH];
    int fd = 0;
    memset(device_name, 0, DEV_NAME_LENGTH);

    if((fgets(device_name, DEV_NAME_LENGTH -1, stdin) == NULL)){
            printf("error in reading from stdin\n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    device_name[DEV_NAME_LENGTH -1] = '\0';

    if ((fd = open(device_name, O_RDWR)) == -1) {
            perror("open failed");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    printf("%s() : Success\n", __FUNCTION__);

}
```

But i am seeing, drivers open() call is not being executed, confirmed from `dmesg`. I am running the program with `sudo` privileges, yet no succsess. I supply the input as `/dev/myscull0`

Infact, after executing the user program, i am seeing two entries in /dev dir

```
vm@vm:/dev$ ls -l | grep scull
crw-r--r-- 1 root    root    247,   1 Feb 27 14:38 myscull0
---Sr-S--- 1 root    root           0 Feb 27 14:38 myscull0
vm@vm:/dev$
```

The first entry was created by me using mknod command, however second entry is created with strange set of permissions after executing the user program.

Output :

```
/dev/myscull0
scull_open() : Success
```

Can anyone pls help what wrong i am doing here ?

Comment: Ok, this is what i figured it out, in user space program is i hard code `/dev/myscull0` in `open()`, then driver code registered with this device file run.  But, it is not working the other way when device file is taken as input from user. Any idea what can be done abt this ?

Comment: From [man fgets] : `If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.`. Probably, this is a reason why you have **two files** with the same name under `/dev`: The first one is the character device, the second one has a name with newline symbol appended. In short, it seems that you **incorrectly read filename from stdin**.